# Button add/remove to collection rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

i'm currently trying to use the associations between groups and cows, and I would like to built a button for this association. To explain the situation, we're into the "*show group*" and it will display a button for each cows. And if the user click on a button, it will create an association between the curent group and the cow.

Actually there is no errors, but the association is not working

My code :

Group_controller :

```
before_action :set_group      

def add_asso
 @cow = Cow.find_by(params[:id])
 @group.cows << @cow
 redirect_to :back
end
```

Show group :

```
<% @ranch = @group.ranch %>
<% @cows = @ranch.cows %>

<%  @cows.each do |c| %>
  <%- if @group.cows.exists?(c.id) %>
    <%= link_to add_asso_group_path(@group.id, c.id), method: :post do %>
    <div class="btn btn-success">
        <%= c.name%>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <% else %>
    <div class="btn btn-info">
        <%= c.name%>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', groups_path %>
```

And finally my routes :

```
resources :groups do 
    member do 
      post :add_asso
      post :rem_asso
    end
  end
```

So if you have any advices about how to run this association, you'll be my HERO !!

Comment: Can you edit your question to be more specific. It what way does it not work? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you that :

**View =**

*Add association =*

```
<%= link_to add_asso_group_path(@group, idz: c.id), method: :post do %>
<div class="btn btn-default">
    <%= c.name%>
</div>
<% end %>
```

*Remove association =*

```
  <%= link_to rem_asso_group_path(@group, idz: c.id), method: :post do %>
    <div class="btn btn-success">
        <%= c.name%>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

**Controller =**

*- Add =*

```
  def add_asso
    @cow = Cow.find(params[:idz])
    @group.cows << @cow
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

*Remove =*

```
  def rem_asso
    @cow = Cow.find(params[:idz])
    @group.cows.delete(@cow)
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

This should work, let me know bro